# Infix expression evaluation in C, the code compiles but it crashes

Tags: c

So I wrote this code to evaluate infix expression like (5*2) + 3 which should return answer 13, and the cde compiles but it crashes in between due to some weird error. I did try debugging it and I think there must be some fault with the logic. But I cant figure it out...
I wrote this code by myself and with some help from the internet. Can you help me find mistake in here? Is the mistake in the logic or some syntax or semantics ?
I tried putting it on code review but it was deleted as my code was 'not working'. I use DevC++ IDE and the error shows  "infivEval.c has stopped working, windows is trying to find a solution" something something...

```
//header files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

//global variables
int numbers[50], tn=-1, to=-1;
char op[50];

//is it digit?
int isItDigit(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case '1':
            return 1;
        case '2':
            return 2;
        case '3':
            return 3;
        case '4':
            return 4;
        case '5':
            return 5;
        case '6':
            return 6;
        case '7':
            return 7;
        case '8':
            return 8;
        case '9':
            return 9;       
    }
    return 0;
}

//function to push digits
void pushNum(int n)
{
    numbers[++tn]=n;
}

//function to push operators
void pushOp(char ch)
{
    op[++to]=ch;
}

//function to pop digits
int popNum()
{
    return numbers[--tn];
}

//function to pop operators
char popOp()
{
    return op[--tn];
}

//actual operation
int actualOperation(int numbers[50], char op[50])
{
    int x,y;
    char opr;
    x=popNum();
    y=popNum();
    opr=popOp();
    
    switch(opr)
    {
        case '+':
            return x+y;
        case '-':
            return y-x;
        case '*':
            return x*y;
        case '/':
            if(x==0)
            {
                printf("\nCannot divide by zero");
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                return y/x;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

//function to check if character is an operator or not
int isOperator(char ch)
{
    switch(ch)
    {
        case '+':
            return '+';
        case '-':
            return '-';
        case '*':
            return '*';
        case '/':
            return '/';
    }
}

//precedence of the operators
int precedence(char ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case '+':
            return 1;
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
            return 2;
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '^':
            return 3;
        
    }
    
    return -1;
}

//to evaluate an infix expression
int evaluateInfix(char expr[50])
{
    int i, num, output, r;
    char c;
    
    for(i=0;expr[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        c = expr[i];
        
        if(isItDigit(c)!=0)
        {
            num = 0;
            while(isItDigit(c))
            {
                num = isItDigit(c);
                i++;
                if(i < strlen(expr))
                {
                    c = expr[i];
                }
                else
                break;
            }
            i--;
            pushNum(num);
        }
        else if(c=='(')
        {
            pushOp(c);
        }
        else if(c==')')
        {
            while(op[to++]!='(')
            {
                r = actualOperation(numbers, op);
                pushNum(r);
            }
            popOp();
        }
        else if(isOperator(c))
        {
            while(to!=-1 && precedence(c)<=precedence(op[to]))
            {
                output = actualOperation(numbers, op);
                pushNum(output);
            }
            pushOp(c);
        }
            

    }
    while(to!=-1)
    {
            output = actualOperation(numbers, op);
            pushNum(output);
    }
    return popNum();
}

//main function
int main()
{
    char expr[50] = "(7-2)+(3*4)";
    int ans = evaluateInfix(expr);
    printf("Answer = %d", ans); 
}
```

Comment: `--tn` and `tn--` do different things...

Comment: @AKX i know they do different things, but i think i havent understood how to use them correctly. What would you suggest?

Comment: Well, if `tn` is `0`, `numbers[++tn]=n;` will touch `numbers[1]`, which is likely not what you want?